# why is my spinner not aligned below my image?

Tags: android, android-spinner

i currently have this issue for where i want to be able to place two spinners side by side with each other and place both of those spinners below the image that I have placed. But why does as seen in the image that i have uploaded below does both of my spinners are being placed above the image? what went wrong here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPgCv.png)

The following below is the code for my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/currency"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginRight="-14dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
        android:text="Curency" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/planets_spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="297dp"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
        android:text="Value" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display view below another view you need to set the `layout_below` property in relative layout.

**Replace**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

**to this**

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```